# MEAN.io init project with ROOT access, or alternative

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, root, mean.io

I am new to MEAN.io, I would like to create new Project. Problem is my PC has default root access and hence I received following error

> Installation of mean should not be done as root! bailing out

Well, I have less knowledge of LINUX and so I don't know the alternative to create the project.

I have searched on Google, and the only result I got is **You can not create project with root access**

Can anyone please help me? Any kind of help will be appreciated.